# How to get rid of a blink while changing one page to another in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a problem with a short black blink while page is changing to another one. My app has only two pages with the same background and this blink can be really annoying. This is how I change pages:

```
MainPage = new Page();
```

I can't use NavigationPage and it's animations because I don't want a navigation bar.

What I've tried so far:

- using only one page with a StackLayout with two grids inside, and changing their visibiliy- doesn't work because StackLayout is creating empty space at the bottom of the page
- using [AnimationNavigationPage](https://github.com/AlexandrNikulin/AnimationNavigationPage) package- I haven't found a solution to animate pages without a navigation bar
- using only one page and modifying visibility of the elements- doesn't work because of differences beetween rows and columns configuration (number of them, width/height) on both pages

Comment: if you create the instances of each page **first**, and then assign them, does that change the problem?

Comment: You mean like this?
`var newPage = new Page();
 App.Current.MainPage = newPage;`
No, unfortunately not.

Comment: yes, but if you create two pages and toggle back and forth WITHOUT creating new instances each time.  The very first time the page is built I might still expect to see the issue. Otherwise I would create both layouts in the same page and toggle visibility.  You don't have to use a StackLayout to do this.

Comment: In 90% of cases my app requires only one page change so the first solution won't work. But I just tried using Grid (instead of StackLayout as I tried before) as a container for my two Grids and it looks good, it may work. Thank you!